# Convert LIst To Dataframe Using For Loop And Saving Under Different Names In R

Tags: r, for-loop, assign

I am trying to convert my list consisting of 52 components to a dataframe for each of the components.
Without using the for loop will look something like this which is tedious:

```
df1 = as.data.frame(list[1])
df2 = as.data.frame(list[2])
df3 = as.data.frame(list[3])
.
.
.
df50 = as.data.frame(list[50])
```

How do I achieve this using the for loop? My attempt:

```
for (i in seq_along(list)) {
  noquote(paste0("df", i)) = as.data.frame(list[i]) 
}

Error: target of assignment expands to non-language objec
```

I think I'll have to invovle `assign`.

Comment: Use `assign` instead of `noquote` i.e. `assign(paste0("df", i), value = list[[i]])` Having said that, it is not recommended.  You can keep the data.frames in a single `list` instead of 50 objects in the global env

Comment: Your life will be much easier if you keep them in a list. You can do `df <- lapply(list, as.data.frame)` to make them data.frames, and then extract with `df[[1]]`, `df[[2]]`, etc.

Comment: Even better save in a named list: `dfs <- setNames(lapply(mylist, as.data.frame), paste0("df", seq_along(mylist)))` to extract as `dfs$df1`, `dfs$df2`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have list of dataframes in `list`, you can name them and then use `list2env` to have them as separate dataframes in the environment.

```
names(list) <- paste0('df', seq_along(list))
list2env(list, .GlobalEnv)
```

Using a reproducible exmaple,

```
temp <- list(mtcars, mtcars)
names(temp) <- paste0('df', seq_along(temp))
list2env(temp, .GlobalEnv)


head(df1)
#                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

head(df2)
#                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

However, note that

- `list` is an internal function in R, so it is better to name your variables something else.
- As @MrFlick suggested try to keep your data in a list as lists are easier to manage rather than creating numerous objects in your global environment.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `assign` instead of `noquote` from the OP's function

```
for (i in seq_along(list)) {
    assign(paste0("df", i), value = list[[i]]) 
    }
```